# Button can't be clicked(.click) because there is no click() event listener

Tags: events, click, listener, event-listener

I'm trying to press a button, which will export data to an excel spreadsheet. This button can be clicked normally, but when I try to click it through `javascript(.click)` it doesn't seem to fire the event. Keep in mind, all the other buttons on this page have the click event listener, but this one doesn't. How do I go about artificially clicking this button?

Comment: Please add your code to the question, it will help understand the context

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is for a confidential website. Is there any other way I could show you it?

Comment: Just send part that are not confidential or remove text that are. At least the button html and the javascript lines that register and trigger the click